# Insert Sub Query inside view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a view in which I have inserted another select statement and labelled that statement as another fields with "alias"

The view got executed successfully but when trying to fire select statement from view (select * from view) it throws an error of

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression
```

Now I'm aware the reason of this error coming. It is because of that the inner select query returns more than 1 row. I cannot go for TOP 1 as I need to have more than one row.

```
 ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TestView_new]
    AS

            SELECT TOP ( 100 ) PERCENT
                        dbo.DataRepository.PeriodStatus ,
                        dbo.DataRepository.TimesheetName ,
                        dbo.DataRepository.TimesheetLineClass ,
                        dbo.DataRepository.TimesheetLineClassUID ,
                        dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceName ,
                                                    dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName AS ProjectName ,
                        ( SELECT MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectName
                          FROM      dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView
                                    LEFT JOIN dbo.DataRepository ON dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[ProjectUID] = dbo.DataRepository.[ProjectUID]
                          WHERE     LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.DataRepository.[ProjectUID])) IS NOT NULL
                                    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.DataRepository.[ProjectUID])) <> '') AS ProjectName2 ,

        FROM    dbo.DataRepository
                    INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_TimesheetActual ON dbo.DataRepository.TimesheetLineUID = dbo.MSP_TimesheetActual.TimesheetLineUID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON dbo.DataRepository.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView ON dbo.DataRepository.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID
```

My Question: Is there any way that the error can be resolved?

Comment: Show your query and DB structure

Comment: How do you want me show the DB structure. Its quite big!. I can show the query.

Comment: How is the project name from the subquery related to the current row? There's no correlation between the main query and the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get more than a single result on a subquery is not possible. You seem to be trying to join MSP_EpmProject_UserView and DataRepository both on the inner query and on the second LEFT OUTER JOIN on the main query. Without the structure of these tables I'm guessing that you have several different ProjectUID for one project name and that is why is returning more than one row. DISTINCT can be usefull if that is the case. If not, then give it a try using GROUP BY clause. Once more, I can not tell more without knowing the tables structures. Hope it helps.